# Is it possible to determine the VirtualBox version within a vagrant plugin?

Tags: ruby, virtualbox, vagrant

I'd like to help patch a bug in the [vagrant-persistent-storage plugin](https://github.com/kusnier/vagrant-persistent-storage/) which is caused by recent versions of VirtualBox (4.3.0r89960) and Vagrant (1.3.5).

Specifically, it seems that VirtualBox has deprecated the `--sataportcount` flag from the `vboxmanage storagectl` command, for the more succinct `--portcount` flag.

I'm not familiar with vagrant plugin development in general, but could easily enough fix the flag in question, if I was able to accurately determine the version of VirtualBox in use.

- Is it possible, within a vagrant plugin, to compare the version of VirtualBox for the purposes of maintaining backwards compatibility with older VirtualBox versions?
- <strike>If not, are there any other vagrant plugins which have to use the command line response from `vboxmanage -v` to make version-specific determinations? I'd prefer to not have to reinvent the wheel...</strike>

Thanks in advance for any tips!

**Update:** I've found that it's possible to get the version as a string within a VirtualBox provider plugin:

```
module VagrantPlugins
  module ProviderVirtualBox
    module Driver
      class Base
        @version
```

However this is just the string representation of the VirtualBox version number (`'4.3.0'`) not a proper version number (`4.3.0`) which would allow strict comparison.  I realize that I could do this comparison myself, but it seems like there should be a way (within Vagrant) to manage VirtualBox/provider dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby can already compare versions as strings.  Like so:

```
irb(main):001:0> '4.3.0' < '4.3.1'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> '1.2.3' < '4.3.0'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> '4.2.17' > '4.3.0'
=> false
```

If you need something more advanced, try the versionmy ruby gem: https://github.com/dazuma/versionomy

Comment: That won't be useful for strings like `'4.3.0'`.